# moving labels closer to edges in a tikz graph

Tags: tikz-trees

In the following plot, how do I move the "y" and "n" labels closer to the corresponding edges?  I can use `pos=...` to move the labels along the edges, but I didn't find a way to move the labels towards the edges.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[tree layout]{
  node1[as=$x_{2}\leq-0.1254968$] -> {
    node2[>"y",>swap,as=$x_{1}\leq-1.591232$] -> {
      node3[>"y",>swap,as=$x_{2}\leq-0.2210189$] -> {
        leaf1[>"y",>swap,draw,as=0.20 0.79 0.00],
        leaf2[>"n",draw,as=0.58 0.16 0.26]
      },
      leaf3[>"n",draw,as=0.34 0.64 0.02]
    },
    leaf4[>"n",draw,as=0.20 0.70 0.10]
  }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: LuaLaTeX output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the `inner sep` of those nodes would be one way. It can be done on a per-node basis with, e.g., `node2[>"y"{inner sep=0},>swap,as=$x_{1}\leq-1.591232$]`, but looks like you want to change it for all the edge labels, so quicker to add

```
edge quotes={auto, inner sep=0}
```

to the options of the `\graph`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[tree layout,
       edge quotes={auto, inner sep=0}
      ]{
  node1[as=$x_{2}\leq-0.1254968$] -> {
    node2[>"y",>swap,as=$x_{1}\leq-1.591232$] -> {
      node3[>"y",>swap,as=$x_{2}\leq-0.2210189$] -> {
        leaf1[>"y",>swap,draw,as=0.20 0.79 0.00],
        leaf2[>"n",draw,as=0.58 0.16 0.26]
      },
      leaf3[>"n",draw,as=0.34 0.64 0.02]
    },
    leaf4[>"n",draw,as=0.20 0.70 0.10]
  }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```